# Foreach Ajax Json - Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

Can anyone help me

I have a Array

```
{"stars":[["Chris Pine","Keira Knightley","Kevin Costner"]]}
```

What i'm trying to do is foreach star i want to append a input to a div and foreach star with they're value inside the input this is what i've so far.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'ajax/get_details.php',
    data: {id: imdb_id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data.stars, function(i, star) {
            $('#stars').append('<input type="text" id="star" value="'+star+'" />');
        });
    },
});
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong please thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{"stars":["Chris Pine","Keira Knightley","Kevin Costner"]}
```

Change it to the above. You currently have an array inside an array.

Or do

```
$.each(data.stars[0], function(i, star) {
            $('#stars').append('<input type="text" id="star" value="'+star+'" />');
        });
```

If you expect to have multiple arrays in the outer array you have to do nested loops