# how to write for loop in jquery

Tags: jquery

Below json is not printing in the for loop.

Please help me to print data as per request in for loop.

**Below code:-**

```
var msg = '{"1":{"plan_id":"1","title":"PocketStore@5","service_id":"SEV557556b","operator":"16","plan_price":null}}';
```

Comment: What for loop? Hard to say what's wrong without seeing the code.

Comment: Print where? Print what? Print how? Be a little more specific

Comment: It is a string, not an object. please make clarity in the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foreach Ajax Json - Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897783/foreach-ajax-json-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```js
var msg = '{"1":{"plan_id":"1","title":"PocketStore@5","service_id":"SEV557556b","operator":"16","plan_price":null}}';
msg = JSON.parse(msg);

$.each(msg,function(i,v){
    console.log(v.plan_id)
    console.log(v.title)
    console.log(v.service_id)
    console.log(v.operator)
    console.log(v.plan_price)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```